# Custom Keyboard to scan barcode and insert the result in the EditText

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, barcode-scanner, textinput

Hello this is my first question
here is the situation: I am working on a costume softkeyboard  with a specific button to scan barcode, it opens the barcode scanner, after it scans, it returns to the previous screen (let's say messaging app) with the result in clip or sharedpreferences. All fine and dandy, except for the fact that the result in the EditText is from the old scan not the new one , because when the first activity get result the scan is not completed at this time (before launching the barcode scanner activity) i was trying to make  handler.postDelayed in the on key function with a boolean test to wait for the scan to finish but this freeze the activity before launching the scan as result i get not responding error 
the on key function is :

```
 case 2017:
            //Toast.makeText(FloatingViewService.this, "NormalScan.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            test=true;
            InputConnection ic  = getCurrentInputConnection();
            ic.deleteSurroundingText(100, 100);  //pour vider le champs de saisair
            Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(SimpleIME.this, NormalScan.class);
            dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity( dialogIntent);
            ic.commitText(String.valueOf(pref.getString("code", null)),1);
```

NormalScan.class to scan barcode is :

```
public class NormalScan  extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ClipboardManager myClipboard;
    private ClipData myClip;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
       // integrator.setOrientationLocked(false);
        integrator.setPrompt("Scan a barcode or QRcode");
        integrator.initiateScan();


        // integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
//        Use this for more customization
//integrator.setOrientationLocked(true);
//        IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);

//        integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ONE_D_CODE_TYPES);

//        integrator.setPrompt("Scan a barcode");

//        integrator.setCameraId(0);  // Use a specific camera of the device

//        integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);

//        integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(true);

//        integrator.initiateScan();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Iconify
                .with(new FontAwesomeModule())
                .with(new EntypoModule())
                .with(new TypiconsModule())
                .with(new MaterialModule())
                .with(new MaterialCommunityModule())
                .with(new MeteoconsModule())
                .with(new WeathericonsModule())
                .with(new SimpleLineIconsModule())
                .with(new IoniconsModule());//// toast library

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

        if (result != null) {
            if (result.getContents() == null) {
                // Toast.makeText(this, "Opération annulée", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //PrettyToast.showError(getApplicationContext(), "Opération annulée");
                new PrettyToast.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                        .withMessage("    Opération annulée  ✘  ") // ☑ ☒ ☓ ✓ ✓ ✕ ✖ ✗ ✘
                        .withDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .withGravity(new PrettyToast.Gravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 15, 0))
                        .withTextSize(24)
                        .withBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_toast_red)
                        .withTextColor(R.color.white)
                        .build()
                        .show();
                //myClipboard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                //String a = new String();
                //a=result.getContents();
                // myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("text","Scan Echouer");
                // myClipboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip);
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //Do something after 100ms

                        handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
                    }
                }, 1500);
                finish();
                setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                //editor.putString("message", "annulée");
                //editor.putString("code", a);
                //editor.commit();
            } else {
                myClipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                String a = new String();
                a = result.getContents();
                myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("text", a);
                myClipboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip);
                //PrettyToast.showSuccess(getApplicationContext(), "Le codebar sauvegarder dans la presse papier","","");
                new PrettyToast.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                        .withMessage("    Scanned   ✓  ") //☑  ✓
                        .withDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .withGravity(new PrettyToast.Gravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 15, 0))
                        .withTextSize(24)
                        .withBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_toast_green)
                        .withTextColor(R.color.white)
                        .build()
                        .show();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Le codebar sauvegarder dans la presse papier",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                finish();
                editor.putString("message", "codebarre");
                editor.putString("code", a);
                editor.putBoolean("testscan", true);
                editor.commit();
                // show keybord

                  // InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(SimpleIME.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                  // imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0);


            }
        }
        else {
            // This is important, otherwise the result will not be passed to the fragment
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            finish();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Launch the activity with startActivityForResult.  When onActivityResult is called, save the barcode scanned.  The next time an inputConnection is established, insert the barcode-  this should be the new connection to the EditText